# What is the problem with the logic in my UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I would appreciate some help with an UPDATE statement.

I want to update `tblOrderHead` with the content from `tblCustomer` where the `intDocumentNo` corresponds to the parameter `@intDocumentNo`. But when I run the my statement, the order table is only updated with the content from the first row of the customer table.

What is the problem with my logic?

I use Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks,

Stefan

```
UPDATE      dbo.tblOrderHead
SET         dbo.tblOrderHead.intCustomerNo   = @intCustomerNo ,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.intPaymentCode  = dbo.tblCustomer.intPaymentCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtDeliveryCode = dbo.tblCustomer.txtDeliveryCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtRegionCode   = dbo.tblCustomer.txtRegionCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtCurrencyCode = dbo.tblCustomer.txtCurrencyCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtLanguageCode = dbo.tblCustomer.txtLanguageCode
FROM        dbo.tblOrderHead
INNER JOIN  dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblOrderHead.intOrderNo = @intDocumentNo
```

---

### Solution

If anyone as stupid as me out there thing the same thing, this is how you solve it:

```
UPDATE      dbo.tblOrderHead
SET         dbo.tblOrderHead.intCustomerNo   = @intCustomerNo ,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.intPaymentCode  = dbo.tblCustomer.intPaymentCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtDeliveryCode = dbo.tblCustomer.txtDeliveryCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtRegionCode   = dbo.tblCustomer.txtRegionCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtCurrencyCode = dbo.tblCustomer.txtCurrencyCode,
            dbo.tblOrderHead.txtLanguageCode = dbo.tblCustomer.txtLanguageCode
FROM        dbo.tblOrderHead
INNER JOIN  dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblOrderHead.intCustomerNo = dbo.tblCustomer.intCustomerNo
AND         dbo.tblOrderHead.intOrderNo = @intDocumentNo
```

Comment: Wouldn't this "dbo.tblOrderHead.intCustomerNo   = @intCustomerNo" make it only update for one customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that, you are not specifying the condition on which the 2 tables `tblOrderHead`,  `tblCustomer` need to be joined!

you need something like

```
INNER JOIN  dbo.tblCustomer 
ON dbo.tblOrderHead.someColumn = dbo.tblCustomer.someColumn
and dbo.tblOrderHead.intOrderNo = @intDocumentNo
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently the problem with the logic was never in my statement but rather in my brain. As so many times before...